# Maven project in intellij not showing run time errors

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, runtime

I am using Intellij IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.5. I am writing a spark application using maven as packet manager. My problem is that run time errors don't get displayed.

For eg.
Say the entered url was http://localhost:4567/query?type=imnrs

Some where in the code if I have:

```
request.queryParams("type1"); // tried to get type parameter but a typo occured
```

Here type1 parameter is not present in the url. So, error must be displayed while running the code. But the error does not get displayed. So, I have to print in every single line to find the error.

The compilation errors get displayed perfectly well. Syntax errors also get highlighted.

A warning get displayed related to logger:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (spark.staticfiles.StaticFilesConfiguration).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Is this the reason for not displaying the error?

I have also tried compiling the project from the terminal and running. Run Time errors don't get displayed that way also.

I use Run window. I also tried looking at event window. I have also tried to invalidate caches. But it didn't work either.

I have already googled to find the answer but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Configure your logger.

Comment: Thanks configuring the logger solved the problem.